# Expectation of ratio between product of gaussian r.v.'s and generalized gamma r.v

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, gamma-distribution, ratio

Given
\begin{equation}\label{eq:definition_of_z}
\begin{split}
\textbf{Z} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
{z}_{11} & {z}_{12} & \cdots & {z}_{1P} \\
{z}_{21} & {z}_{22} & \cdots & {z}_{2P} \\
{z}_{31} & {z}_{32} & \cdots & {z}_{3P} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{z}_{M1} & {z}_{M2} & \cdots & {z}_{MP} \\ \end{array} \right] =  \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{P} \\ \end{array} \right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where the $z_{mp}$ are i.i.d. $\forall \ m,p$ with distribution $z_{mp} \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,c)$ and $\textbf{z}_{i}$ represents each of the columns of  $\textbf{Z} \sim \mathcal{CN}(\textbf{0}_{M \times P},\text{cM}\textbf{I}_{P})$.

Other necessary definition is given by

\begin{equation}\label{eq:definition_of_z_z}
\textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z} =  \left[\begin{array}{c}
\textbf{z}_{1}^{H} \\
\textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \\
\vdots \\
\textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \\ \end{array} \right]  \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{P} \\ \end{array} \right] = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{1}^{H} \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{1}^{H} \textbf{z}_{P} \\
\textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \textbf{z}_{P} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \textbf{z}_{P} \\ \end{array} \right] 
\end{equation}

Next we define the following ratio:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:channel_matrix}
  \frac{ \textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z} }{ \text{Tr} \left(    \textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z}     \right)^{2} } = \frac{ \textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z} }{ \left(   \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}     \right)^{2} }   
\end{equation}

where $\text{Tr}$ is the Trace operator.

It is important to note that the elements of the main diagonal of $\textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z}$, namely  $\textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1}, \ \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2}, \ \cdots, \  \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P} \sim \Gamma(M,2c)$.

I'd like to prove that the following expectation is equal to 0.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
\mathbb{E} \left\lbrace \frac{\textbf{z}_{i}^{H}\textbf{z}_{j}}{\left(   \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}     \right)^{2} } \right\rbrace = 0, \ \text{when} \  i \neq j.
\end{equation}

I know for a fact that the above statement is true due to some Matlab simulations I ran but I'd like to prove that mathematically.

It's also worth mentioning that $\textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}$ results in a scalar random variable.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the notation; are the $z_{ij}$ iid?

Comment: @Dougal, I've just fixed the notations and added more information and yes, $z_{mp}$ are i.i.d. $\forall \ m,p$ with distribution $z_{mp} \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,c)$. I hope this answers your question.